# Is it possible to "extend" the life of shared memory?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu-shared-memory

I have a kernel where I use some shared memory. I copy an automaton to shared memory, execute some pattern matching, get some results and exit.

After exiting this kernel, I call this same kernel and copy the same automaton to shared memory, but now the data that will be tested on the pattern matching is different.

I want to know if i can leave this data (automaton) in shared memory, so my program will be faster, copying the automaton to shared memory just in the first time.

Does there exist any sync function that can be called from device to tell to the host that a kernel has finished, so I can execute the kernel again from the beginning without clearing shared memory.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think it is possible. Shared memory data is logically associated to a specific thread block and physically associated to a specific streaming multiprocessor, but a thread block is not physically associated to a specific streaming multiprocessor.

Comment: Do you know if exists any sync function that can synchronize host with kernel?

Comment: @Blufter `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`. Remember that `cudaMemcpy` is blocking the host and thus produces a synchronization between host and device.

Answer (score 3):

It's not even possible to keep shared memory for the whole execution of a particular kernel. Shared memory is specific to a threadblock and you cannot predict when a specific block will begin and end its execution. You can, of course, keep data in global memory between kernel executions which is probably fine for this application. After all, you're going to have to load that new data from global memory anyway.